# Setting position of the header text right above the other content in CSS

Tags: html, css

This issue is related to the topic mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630935/how-to-put-text-in-the-center-of-box-while-using-border-box-in-css/29632216#29632216). 
I managed to fix my previous CSS code to get the effect of having text aligned to the middle of the picture, but now I would like to add a header to the text. My problem is that I have troubles with aligning the header, currently it looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/u8db2j75/ , but I would like to achieve the effect like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRTyh.png where the header text is right above the normal text. I don't know why in my solution there's this huge gap between the header and the text. Could you help me with my issue? My current css code is as follows:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 60rem;
  /* 960 */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.item {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  display:table;
  /* 80 */
}
.item__img,
.item__info {
  width: 50%;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.item__img {} .item__img .img-map {
  width: 95%;
  height: 18.750rem;
  /* 300 */
}
.item__img img {
  width: 95%;
  height: 18.750rem;
  /* 300 */
}
h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 4rem;
    /* 64 */
    text-align: left;
}
```

and current html code is this:

```
<div class="container" role="main">

  <article class="item">

    <div class="item__img">
      <div class="img-map">
        <img src="http://biologypop.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/dog1.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item__info">
    <h2>HEADER</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ac sodales orci. Praesent sit amet consequat purus. Praesent lobortis mi quis rutrum fringilla. Phasellus velit arcu, ultricies vestibulum varius sed, convallis ut eros. Vestibulum
        vel congue felis, ut lacinia tellus. Integer ullamcorper gravida ligula non convallis. Ut suscipit vulputate erat eu porttitor. Morbi sagittis vulputate bibendum. Aliquam ultricies finibus tortor, a elementum nisl aliquet at. In sed dui id mauris
        rutrum ornare.</p>
    </div>

  </article>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a heading followed by a paragraph, there are (generally) no more than 4 style declarations that create a visible vertical gap between the heading and the paragraph. These 4 style declarations are (in order):

1) The `padding-bottom` of the heading;

2) The `margin-bottom` of the heading;

3) The `margin-top` of the paragraph;

4) The `padding-top` of the paragraph;

*With more advanced layouts, declarations like `line-height` will also play a role, but we don't need to worry about that for now.*

Therefore, if you want to ensure that there is zero visible gap between the second-level heading and the paragraph which follows it, you might declare the following rules:

```
h2 {
margin-bottom: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
}

p {
margin-top: 0;
padding-top: 0;
}
```

Of course, if we leave it there, the style rules for the paragraph above will apply to *all* paragraphs. If we want these style rules to apply *only* to paragraphs which immediately follow an `<h2>`, then we can make the styles above slightly more explicit by declaring:

```
h2 {
margin-bottom: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
}

h2 + p {
margin-top: 0;
padding-top: 0;
}
```

The `+` selector above indicates that the rules only apply to the *element after the selector* when it is the sibling which immediately follows the *element before the selector*.

Now that you have zero visible gap between the `<h2>` and the `<p>`, you can tweak your margins and paddings as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this lies in the answer I gave on the previous question. There's spacing because the browser applies it's own stylesheet.

Here's what firefox adds:

```
h2, *:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section) h1 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0.83em 0;
}
```

You just need to add a style that overwrites the margin.

As I mentioned before, you can use a developer console either in Google Chrome, or by adding Firebug to Firefox. This will allow you to see what styles are being applied to which elements on the page, just by pressing F12.

Comment: Thanks, but am I not overwrite it by using my own stylesheet for h2:
`h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 4rem;
    /* 64 */
    text-align: left;
}` 
? If not, what else should I overwrite here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must reduce the bottom margin of h2 (53px) and the top margin of

(16px)

```
h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 4rem;
    /* 64 */
    text-align: left;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
p{
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the code and you'll see a margin applied to your `<h2>` :

[image]

This is caused by default CSS value.

It is very recommended you add `* {padding: 0; margin: 0;}` to disable default padding/margin on every element, then you'll be able to add your own margins/paddings on whatever you want.